# error inversa de una matriz?

Tags: python

tengo la siguiente matriz

```
Y =   

  (0, 0)        -17.3611111111j
  (3, 0)        17.3611111111j
  (7, 1)        16j
  (1, 1)        -16j
  (2, 2)        -17.0648464164j
  (5, 2)        17.0648464164j
  (8, 3)        (-1.36518771331+11.6040955631j)
  (3, 3)        (3.30737896203-39.3088887261j)
  (0, 3)        17.3611111111j
  (4, 3)        (-1.94219124871+10.5106820519j)
  (4, 4)        (3.22420038714-15.8409270142j)
  (3, 4)        (-1.94219124871+10.5106820519j)
  (5, 4)        (-1.28200913842+5.58824496236j)
  (5, 5)        (2.43709661931-32.1538618051j)
  (2, 5)        17.0648464164j
  (4, 5)        (-1.28200913842+5.58824496236j)
  (6, 5)        (-1.15508748089+9.78427042636j)
  (6, 6)        (2.77220995414-23.3032490233j)
  (5, 6)        (-1.15508748089+9.78427042636j)
  (7, 6)        (-1.61712247325+13.6979785969j)
  (7, 7)        (2.80472685254-35.4456131302j)
  (6, 7)        (-1.61712247325+13.6979785969j)
  (8, 7)        (-1.18760437929+5.97513453331j)
  (1, 7)        16j
  (8, 8)        (2.5527920926-17.3382300964j)
  (7, 8)        (-1.18760437929+5.97513453331j)
  (3, 8)        (-1.36518771331+11.6040955631j)
```

utilizo

```
from numpy import linalg 
Zb=np.linalg.inv(Y)
```

y me sale el siguiente error

LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional

estoy editando un programa el cual me vota los datos como en el ejemplo anterior, la matriz si es cuadrada, de la forma normal es la siguiente

```
x =      np.array ([[-17.3611111111j,   0,  0,  17.3611111111j, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
                    [0, -16j,      0,     0,    0,  0,  0,  16j,    0],
                    [0, 0,     -17.0648464164j,   0,    0,  17.0648464164j, 0,  0,  0],
                    [17.3611111111j,    0,  0,  (3.30737896203-39.3088887261j),     (-1.94219124871+10.5106820519j),       0,      0,      0,      (-1.36518771331+11.6040955631j)],
                    [0, 0,  0,  (-1.94219124871+10.5106820519j),  (3.22420038714-15.8409270142j),   (-1.28200913842+5.58824496236j),    0,     0,       0],
                    [0, 0,  17.0648464164j, 0,      (-1.28200913842+5.58824496236j),       (2.43709661931-32.1538618051j),     (-1.15508748089+9.78427042636j),   0,       0    ],
                    [0, 0,  0,  0,      0   ,   (-1.15508748089+9.78427042636j),       (2.77220995414-23.3032490233j),    (-1.61712247325+13.6979785969j),    0 ],
                    [0, 16j,    0,  0,  0,  0,  (-1.61712247325+13.6979785969j),    (2.80472685254-35.4456131302j),   (-1.18760437929+5.97513453331j)],
                    [0, 0,     0,     (-1.36518771331+11.6040955631j),    0,       0,   0,  (-1.18760437929+5.97513453331j),    (2.5527920926-17.3382300964j)]])
```

ahi si me sale la inversa, pero quiero obtener la inversa da la matriz del primer ejemplo, que es la misma solo que con otra notación

o me pueden decir como transformo la matriz del primer ejemplo en el segundo

Comment: Podrias subir la matriz con el formato correcto? Quiero probar ese codigo pero el intel y el pep 8 me da errores por todos lados

Answer (score 0):

La funcion linalg.inv requiere como parametro una matriz cuadrada (n*n) en primer lugar, y completa tendrias que llenar el resto de las posiciones con ceros, por otro lado es posible que la matriz no tenga una matriz inversa.

Comment: como puedo llenar la matriz con ceros, que no sea de forma manual?

Comment: puedes escribir como construyes  la primera matriz (a detalle), para poder ayudarte

Comment: (n,n) es la coordenada y el numero va en esa posición

Answer (score -1):

el error ese es porque la matriz no es invertible, osea no se pueden invertir todas

tiene que ser cuadrada para empezar.

ese error se da cuando o la matriz no es cuadrada o no se puede invertir debido a que no existe la matriz inversa.

[fijate esta definicion de matriz invertible](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_invertible)

Comment: vota? osea no te la acepta? eso como te decia , la matriz puede que no tenga matriz invertible o no la acepta porque no es cuadrada. lo que es extraño porque vi una posicion que dice (8,8). probaste rellenar todas las posiciones?