# cambiar notacion matriz?

Tags: python

tengo una matriz dela siguiente forma

```
Y =   

  (0, 0)        -17.3611111111j
  (3, 0)        17.3611111111j
  (7, 1)        16j
  (1, 1)        -16j
  (2, 2)        -17.0648464164j
  (5, 2)        17.0648464164j
  (8, 3)        (-1.36518771331+11.6040955631j)
  (3, 3)        (3.30737896203-39.3088887261j)
  (0, 3)        17.3611111111j
  (4, 3)        (-1.94219124871+10.5106820519j)
  (4, 4)        (3.22420038714-15.8409270142j)
  (3, 4)        (-1.94219124871+10.5106820519j)
  (5, 4)        (-1.28200913842+5.58824496236j)
  (5, 5)        (2.43709661931-32.1538618051j)
  (2, 5)        17.0648464164j
  (4, 5)        (-1.28200913842+5.58824496236j)
  (6, 5)        (-1.15508748089+9.78427042636j)
  (6, 6)        (2.77220995414-23.3032490233j)
  (5, 6)        (-1.15508748089+9.78427042636j)
  (7, 6)        (-1.61712247325+13.6979785969j)
  (7, 7)        (2.80472685254-35.4456131302j)
  (6, 7)        (-1.61712247325+13.6979785969j)
  (8, 7)        (-1.18760437929+5.97513453331j)
  (1, 7)        16j
  (8, 8)        (2.5527920926-17.3382300964j)
  (7, 8)        (-1.18760437929+5.97513453331j)
  (3, 8)        (-1.36518771331+11.6040955631j)
```

quiero obtener

```
x =      np.array ([[-17.3611111111j,   0,  0,  17.3611111111j, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
                    [0, -16j,      0,     0,    0,  0,  0,  16j,    0],
                    [0, 0,     -17.0648464164j,   0,    0,  17.0648464164j, 0,  0,  0],
                    [17.3611111111j,    0,  0,  (3.30737896203-39.3088887261j),     (-1.94219124871+10.5106820519j),       0,      0,      0,      (-1.36518771331+11.6040955631j)],
                    [0, 0,  0,  (-1.94219124871+10.5106820519j),  (3.22420038714-15.8409270142j),   (-1.28200913842+5.58824496236j),    0,     0,       0],
                    [0, 0,  17.0648464164j, 0,      (-1.28200913842+5.58824496236j),       (2.43709661931-32.1538618051j),     (-1.15508748089+9.78427042636j),   0,       0    ],
                    [0, 0,  0,  0,      0   ,   (-1.15508748089+9.78427042636j),       (2.77220995414-23.3032490233j),    (-1.61712247325+13.6979785969j),    0 ],
                    [0, 16j,    0,  0,  0,  0,  (-1.61712247325+13.6979785969j),    (2.80472685254-35.4456131302j),   (-1.18760437929+5.97513453331j)],
                    [0, 0,     0,     (-1.36518771331+11.6040955631j),    0,       0,   0,  (-1.18760437929+5.97513453331j),    (2.5527920926-17.3382300964j)]])
```

Comment: La matriz que dices que tienes ¿dónde la tienes? Quiero decir, lo que pones al principio de `Y = ` obviamente no es una asignación python, pues no sería sintácticamente correcta. Entiendo que es una forma de presentarnos lo que contendria la variable pero ¿de dónde sale? ¿es una lista de tuplas? ¿un diccionario? ¿está en un fichero? y en este caso ¿en qué formato?

Comment: Y esta pregunta no es la misma que [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/239295/7123) ? Si hay alguna diferencia aclárala, si no, por favor no dupliques preguntas. Añade si acaso a la anterior (editando la pregunta) lo que quieras aclarar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo es que inicialices un array de complejos de la dimensión adecuada (8x8 en este caso), todo con ceros, así:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((9,9), dtype=complex)
```

para después ir recorriendo tu estructura `Y`, extrayendo la tupla  `(i, j)`con los índices del elemento y el valor `v` que debe ir en él, para hacer `x[i,j]=v`.

El cómo realizar esa iteración depende de cómo sea la variable `Y` (¿una lista de tuplas y valores? ¿Un diccionario cuyas claves son las tuplas?), si es que es una variable, ya que quizás sea el contenido de un fichero. No has aclarado esto aunque se te ha preguntado en un comentario.

Supondré de momento el caso más simple, y es que `Y` sea un diccionario cuyas claves son tuplas como `(0,0)`, `(3,0)` y los valores son los datos a guardar en `x`. Entonces:

```
for (i,j), v in Y.items():
    x[i,j] = v
```